# Vault command gives "Unable to Mount fileSystem" when trying to download CQ dependency jars

Tags: maven, jar, adobe, aem

I am trying to setup Core project using CQ. I have the Maven project created in Eclipse but when I try to fetch the jar dependencies (cq-wcm-api-5.5.0.jar etc) using vault command "vlt co", I get the below error:

[WARN ] Authentication required to access repository descriptors
[ERROR] checkout: com.day.jcr.vault.vlt.VltException: Unable to mount filesystem

caused by: javax.jcr.ItemNotFoundException: Not Found
caused by: org.apache.jackrabbit.webdav.DavException: Not Found

I checked crx-de to confirm if the jar is present in the path but still getting this error.

How to avoid this or is there an alternate way to download these jar dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After banging my head with different solutions, this is what I came up with:

1. CQ Jars cannot be checked out using vault command. An alternative to this is to create a package in package explorer of CQ and add filters corresponding to the required jar. Once the package gets built, we can access the jar directly. **"But this is not a good approach"**
2. Solution to point 1 is to use the power of Maven. We just need to provide the dependency to POM.xml and Maven does all the downloading stuff for us. But there is again a catch here. Even tough we might give the dependency, Maven will not be able to download the dependencies.
   Reason: Adobe doesnt want it to. The repository is not accessible directly.
   Solution: Use profiles in POM.xml to enable Maven to download the jars.

The Profiles can be accessed below:
http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/core/how_to/how_to_use_the_vlttool/vlt-mavenplugin.html#Obtaining%20the%20Content%20Package%20Maven%20Plugin

The solution I found out was in the below link:
http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/core/how_to/how_to_use_the_vlttool/vlt-mavenplugin.html